# appspec.yml for reactjs app on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am deploying my nodejs react application on aws and I am using EC2 and CodeDeploy. I am almost there but my deployment is getting failed because there is no appspec.yml file in the project. I have created an appspec.yml file in my project and took a boilerplate code from github for it

It looks like this right now

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
   - source: /
     destination: /var/www/html
permissions:
   - object: /var/www/html
     pattern: "**"
     owner: apache
     group: apache
     mode: 755
     type:
       - file
hooks:
   BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/installapache.sh
      runas: root
    - location: scripts/startapache.sh
      runas: root
   AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/restartapache.sh
      runas: root
```

This is a boiler plate code. But for my applciation I need to run these commands

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn install --ignore-scripts
gulp
```

How should I include these in an appspec.yml file? Can someone show how should it look?

Also do it need to change permissions fields (in appspec.yml) depending on the project structure?

Comment: You may need CodeBuild Before CodeDeploy

Comment: And why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Those installation commands are more suited for EC2 User Data. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html for instructions.